# How to use azure sql for multiple interface framework 

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, azure, azure-sql-database

i want to create few application with the same database gonna host in azure, may i know how can i achieve this while there're no exact framework or tutorial for this. "maybe i got no idea on what the keyword is".

The main application i built is silverlight + silverlight.web with entity framework. the silverlight application talk with web solution via RIA services. and the database is mdf file. is there any possible to make the mdf host in azure sql, the silverlight application host in azure and the mobile silverlight, wpf need to get the data from azure sql with any way.

Please guide me out, Thank you =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial should get you going.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-in-the-Azure-cloud-Part-1.aspx

and

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-in-the-Azure-cloud-Part-2.aspx

The whole catch is to get used to Azure. Everything else is straight forward from there.

About migrating an mdf file to SQL Azure i think you will have to convert it to a .bacpac file and then import it into SqlAzure. I believe you will find enough details about this on the web.

I hope this helps.

Comment: if i want to talk to the sql azure with wpf or mobile silverlight ?? also use the domain context ?? Thx for reply =D

Comment: take a look here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-WCF-RIA-Services-strategies-for-handling-your-Domain-Context-part-one.aspx  and for part 2 here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-WCF-RIA-Services-strategies-for-handling-your-Domain-Context-part-two.aspx

Comment: Can silverlight connect to Sql Azure directly (like ado.net)? I mean without some service

Comment: yes! inside your windows azure management dashboard, you have a section on the right side where you can generate your connection string.

here is a link on how to achieve this: http://f5debug.net/2011/06/16/sql-azure-getting-connection-strings-generated-in-azure-portal/